# Backbone events hash depends on data created during rendering

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, jquery-events

I have a Backbone view whose render method creates and caches some JavaScript objects then renders them out to SVG nodes in the DOM. So (*very* simplistically), I'm doing something like this:

```
render: function() {
  // Create objects and cache them to the view...
  this.someObjects = [obj1, obj2, ...];
  // Render objects...
  this.someObjects.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.render(); // Each object knows how to render itself...
  })
  return this;
}
```

My view events hash is returned from a function, and contains event handlers which close over certain variables which depend on the objects cached when rendering. So (again simplistically, just for illustration purposes), I'm doing something like this:

```
events: function() {
  var getRenderedObjects = function() {
    return this.someObjects;
  };
  var renderedObjects = getRenderedObjects();

  return {
    'click #someDiv .someClass' : function() {
      console.log(renderedObjects);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that Backbone sets up the bindings for the events hash before the view initialization function runs, which is where I need to do an explicit render. So `this.someObjects` will be `undefined`. Before moving to Backbone all my event handlers were defined and bound after rendering the view, which seemed natural anyway. I have found a workaround, which is to set the events hash manually on initialization, after rendering, and then call `delegateEvents()` to ensure they're bound. This works, although I found that within the handlers `this` no longer refers to the view object, but rather to the global window object again. It all seems rather cumbersome and a bit hackish, however.

I guess I *could* leave `renderedObjects` as `null` and set it conditionally in the handler which requires it (so if it's not set, set it, else do nothing). That seems ugly, though. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why can't your events call methods in your view? Why do they have to be bound to anonymous functions?

Comment: @TJ The example is a gigantic oversimplification. I'm not actually doing that. They aren't even the real variable and method names. The point is that it _wouldn't_ be undefined if Backbone set up the events binding after rendering.

Comment: @muistooshort Of course I could do that. But I want to keep things clean and self-contained, I don't want to have lots of methods and variables hanging off the View object. Even if I did define them directly on the View it wouldn't make any difference, because Backbone would still be binding the handlers before rendering happens.

Comment: Why does "Backbone would still be binding the handlers before rendering happens" matter at all? Backbone attaches a single event handler to the view's `el` and the events are handled through delegation and `render` puts things *inside* `el` so the order shouldn't matter. Maybe a more accurate example would help; sounds like you invented some way of doing things with plain jQuery and now you want Backbone to do things exactly the same way, also sounds like you have some sort of mega-view that is trying to do everything.

Comment: @ChrisM  The problem is with the way you're doing things. You should come up with a realistic example of why you must do things this way and why it can never be solved as long as backbone binds event handlers before initialize.